# Spring framework to pass Connection object to legacy code

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC 3.0.6. I also have legacy code which uses plain JDBC. There are methods in the legacy code which required java.sql.Connection object. I want to call this method from my Spring code. How can I pass the java.sql.Connection object?

If I take connection object from the datasource then I need to manage the return/release of this connection. Can I not just get the reference of a connection object which is in the transaction.

I am using annotation based configuration and aop based declarative transactions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`JdbcTemplate.execute(ConnectionCallback)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback%29). The connection callback will have access to the connection which is automatically opened, closed and associated to the current transaction by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataSourceUtils.getConnection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection%28javax.sql.DataSource%29) method, this will retreive the connection associated with the transaction. Use [DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#releaseConnection%28java.sql.Connection,%20javax.sql.DataSource%29) to release it (a noop if the connection is the one associated with the Transaction.

If the legacy code has util classes to open / close connection - you can just modify that to use the DataSourceUtils functions.

Comment: This will not work for me as I do not want to write release connection. Since spring provides all the connection handling I want to stay away from that.

Comment: You don't have to call releaseConnection if you are sure that the connection you retreived was the one associated with Transaction.

Comment: How do I know that? I used DataSourceUtils.getConnection(datasource) and passed the datasource reference. I got the connection but the connection never returned.

Comment: The call needs to happen in the context of a spring managed transaction (a method annotated by @Transactional).